# I don't understand difference between changing the random state in Train Test split and in the MLP regressor

Tags: scikit-learn, neural-network, theory, random-seed, mlp

I am trying to figure out the difference between the random state in train test split and in the MLP regressor.
If I change it in the MLP regressor all the trials I run are very good. However, if I change it in the train test split I have a wide range of results. I read that both are the random seed but I don't understand how they affect so differently to my MLP depending on where I change it.

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you have some code like the one from the scikit-example [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPRegressor.html):

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y,random_state=1)
regr = MLPRegressor(random_state=1, max_iter=500).fit(X_train, y_train)
```

And first you changed the random state in **train_test_split** and then you changed it in **MLPRegressor** and compared it.

When changing the random_state in train_test_split method, it will shuffle your data a bit differently according to your random_state than before, so your train and test data looks different. ([Documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html))

When changing the random_state of the MLPRegressor, it not only uses that seed to shuffle your data in the train_test_split method, but also to generate the weights, initialize the bias and determine batch sampling. ([Documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPRegressor.html))

So changing the random state in MLPRegressor entails more changes than just changing the train_test_split random state. Hope I understood your question correctly and could help you.

Comment: Yes you understood my question correctly. Thank you for answering.
I do have a couple of questions to your answer:
-So then changing the random_state in the MLP regressor also suffles the train/test split?
-If changing the random state in MLPregressor entails more changes and I have very good results, does it mean my network is robust to changes?
-If changing the random state in the train test split generates very good and very bad outcomes, does it mean my network is not robust?
That's my dilemma and the thing I don't understand.